# Getting undefined values from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I am getting response something like this in the form JavaScript Object

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "invoice_prefix": "INV",
            "maximum_invoice_no": "0009"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to fetch the value of invoice_prefix and maximum_invoice_no
I have written result[0].maximum_invoice_no but I am getting undefined . 
I have tried a lot of other ways also but still getting undefined . Please help me and give me some hint

Comment: What is `result`? If you call entire object to be `result` then it should be `result.result[0].maximum_invoice_no`

Comment: What does it show if you do `alert(result[0])`? Is that already `undefined`?

Comment: Let's not fill up the comments section with guess answers. That wastes our time and encourages people to ask bad questions. Let the OP provide a [mcve] first.

Comment: You may need to access response.result[0].maximum_invoice_no where response is the variable which holds that Javascript Object

Comment: Yes I have done console.log(result[0] ) it is showing null

Comment: @Vikas — There are no `null` values anywhere in your code (and they won't typically be created implicitly (like `undefined`)). So there is something clearly lacking in what you've put in the question. You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: Sorry but I have got the solution . I have followed your suggestion@PeterB thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that and it is working as expected. I hope this will be helpful.

```js
let test = {
    "result": [
        {
            "invoice_prefix": "INV",
            "maximum_invoice_no": "0009"
        }
    ]
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Maximum Invoice No. : " + test.result[0].maximum_invoice_no;

console.log(test.result[0].maximum_invoice_no);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```